# MongoDB & Mongoose query returns null for aggregate $or search with non-matching field, returns individual searches or with undefined value omitted

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm a bit confused by the behavior I'm seeing in a Mongoose/MongoDB query, as it seems that the `$or` operator is being treated as an `$and`

I have the following Collection Document that I am querying for:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5bd0d709ff8eef5d5325090f"
    },
    "audienceTrackingID": "3e66c213-fe0b-4096-a99c-558a6c349b4b",
    "mainframeTrackingID": null,
    "partner1TrackingID": "85c5f168-08da-44d3-bbef-fbb3b8392ded",
    "__v": 0,
    "contentFocus": "Cooking",
    "ipRange": [
        "29.142.127.151"
    ]
}
```

With the following query:

```
console.log(req.headers['x-original-ip']) // '29.142.127.151'
console.log(req.headers['x-audience-tracking-id']) // undefined
console.log(req.headers['x-partner-1-tracking-id']) // "85c5f168-08da-44d3-bbef-fbb3b8392ded"

const clientMatch = await Client.findOne({
    $or: [{ 
        ipRange: req.headers['x-original-ip'],  
        audienceTrackingID: req.headers['x-audience-tracking-id'],
        partner1TrackingID: req.headers['x-partner-1-tracking-id'],
    }]
})

console.log(clientMatch) // null
```

Somewhat puzzling, as querying for individual fields, as well as removing my query where the param is undefined within the actual query (`req.headers['x-audience-tracking-id']`) will produce results (Which makes me wonder, why is this acting like an AND and giving me null when one queryfield fails???)

```
// ALL QUERIES HIT AND RETURN A MATCH:

const tryThis = await Client.findOne({partner1TrackingID: req.headers['x-partner-1-tracking-id']})
const ipMatch = await Client.findOne({ipRange: req.headers['x-original-ip']})
const clientMatch = await Client.findOne({
    $or: [{ 
        ipRange: req.headers['x-original-ip'],  
        partner1TrackingID: req.headers['x-partner-1-tracking-id'],
    }]
})
```

It makes no sense to me. Why would I need to omit a field which may not match from an $or operator in order to get a hit, when other fields match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you try to run your query you actually get:

```
query failed: cannot compare to undefined
```

See [this here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3ZjmJJyorev)

This is one reason you get no results, another is that your `$or` query is not correct. You need to separate the `or-ed` items into separate objects for MongoDB:

So change your code to this:

```
const clientMatch = await Client.findOne({
    $or: [
        {ipRange: req.headers['x-original-ip']},  
        {audienceTrackingID: req.headers['x-audience-tracking-id'] || ''},
        {partner1TrackingID: req.headers['x-partner-1-tracking-id']},
    ]
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your helpful response. I will change my query -- Just one question, it appears that in your edit, there is a missing `{` right after the `[` which defines the `or` statement, correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Although I am also a bit confused - the following query works without separating out the `or-ed` statements, are you 100% certain that it is required to separate them? :: `Client.findOne({
   $or: [{ 
    ipRange: req.headers['x-original-ip'], 
    partner1TrackingID: req.headers['x-partner-1-tracking-id'],
   }]
  })`

Comment: Yep I left one by mistake when typing. Thanks. Should be fixed now

Comment: This returns no documents: https://mongoplayground.net/p/ta1Oi1GnjlD
This returns result: https://mongoplayground.net/p/CEGHxQLJf96
Seems like they have to be

Comment: Interesting O.o, perhaps mongoose could be aiding my broken query in some way? Either way, thank you very much!

Comment: It could be that is a good point. I am giving you the raw mongo output. Glad it helped.